# Seleccionar fila de un datatable que itera sobre una colección

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la facultad que consiste en préstamos de dinero, pago de cuotas y cancelación de los mismos​.

Cuando muestro los préstamos en un datatable, selecciono alguno y muestro sus respectivas cuotas (están en una collection), luego ya no sé cómo seleccionar esa cuota para pagarla.

Código:

```
<!--El selected es un préstamo seleccionado-->
<p:dataTable id="datatable" paginator="true" widgetVar="tablaPrestamo"
  rows="7" value="#{prestamoDataController.prestamoLista}" var="item" 
  rowKey="#{item.idprestamo}" 
  selectionMode="single" 

  selection="#{prestamoDataController.selected}" 
  resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" style="margin-bottom:20px"
  scrollable="true"
  filteredValue="#{prestamoDataController.filtered}"
  emptyMessage="No se encontro ningun cliente"
> 

<p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
  oncomplete="PF('editwidgetVar').show();" 
  update=":form:growl,:form:displayEdit"/>
```

Sigue más abajo la parte de la colección:

```
<p:dialog id="editDialog" header="#{app['dialog.edit']}" widgetVar="editwidgetVar" 
  resizable="false" height="400" width="550" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold"> 

<h:panelGrid id="displayEdit" columns="2" title="#{app['dialog.edit']}"> 

<p:panelGrid columns="2">


<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" 
  value="#{prestamoDataController.selected.cuotaCollection}" 
  rowKey="#{c.nroCuota}"
  var="c">

<f:facet name="header">
  Listado de Cuotas
</f:facet>
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="id."/>
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{c.idcuota}"/>
</p:column>
```

y en con este botón debería pagar las cuotas seleccionadas:

```
<p:commandButton value="Pagar" action="#" 
   onclick="return confirm('¿Esta Seguro?')"/>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más claro con tu pregunta? No se entiende muy bien el problema ¿A qué te refieres con " luego ya no se como seleccionar esa cuota para pagarla"?

Comment: Te refieres a que seleccionas del primer data table x prestamo, se abre un Dialog que contiene el data table, y tu duda es. ¿ Cómo obtener un valor seleccionado de este segundo data table ?

Comment: Les pido disculpas por no haber sido claro.

Es como dice @Voiser

Selecciono una fila del datatable prestamo, y eso abre un dialog que contiene  otro datatable con las cuotas correspondientes al prestamo seleccionado. 

Mi pregunta es :
¿Como seleccionar y obtener un valor de este segundo datatable ?

Gracias

Comment: Indica la versión de prime faces que usas, por ejemplo yo con 3.5 he usado algo como esto: 
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){

        
        this.unObjeto = (UnCASToClase)event.getObject();
}

Comment: Muchas gracias @Voiser , tu ayuda me permitió resolver mi problema .

Saludos